# Is there any difference between using “MIT-style curried-procedure forms” and lambda-expressions passed to the `curry` function?

Tags: racket

Given the code snippet that follows, is there any meaningful difference between `example-func-A` and `example-func-B`?

```
#lang racket/base

(require (only-in racket/function curry))

(define (((example-func-A x) y) z)
  (+ x y z))

(define example-func-B
  (curry
   (lambda (x y z)
     (+ x y z))))
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `example-func-A` (which uses the MIT-style curried-procedure syntax) is less flexible than `example-func-B`, in that it expects to only be called *with a single argument at a time*:

```
> (((example-func-A 4) 5) 6)
15
> (example-func-A 4 5 6)
example-func-A: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 1
  given: 3
  arguments...:
   4
   5
   6
  context...:
   /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/racket/6.4/Racket v6.4/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

In contrast, `example-func-B` accommodates receiving multiple (or even zero!) arguments:

```
> (((example-func-B 4) 5) 6)
15
> (example-func-B 4 5 6)
15
> ((((example-func-B) 4)) 5 6)
15
```

(Presumably the flexibility of `curry` comes with a bit of a performance hit at runtime.)